# Faster similarity clustering in python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, similarity

I have a collection of a few thousand strings (DNA sequences).  I want to trim this down to a couple of hundred (exact number not critical) by excluding sequences that are very similar.

I can do this via matching using the "Levenshtein" module.  It works, but it's pretty slow, and I'm pretty sure there must be a much faster way.  The code here is the same approach but applied to words, to make it more testable; for me with this cutoff it takes about 10 seconds and collects ~1000 words.

```
import Levenshtein as lev
import random
f = open("/usr/share/dict/words", 'r')
txt = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()
cutoff = .5
collected = []
while len(txt) > 0:
    a = random.choice(txt)
    collected.append(a)
    txt = filter( lambda b: lev.ratio(a,b) < cutoff, txt)
```

I've tried a few different variations and some other matching modules (Jellyfish) without getting significantly faster.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use locality-sensitve hashing. You could hash all strings into buckets so that all strings in one bucket are very similar to each other. Than you can pick just one of each bucket.

I've never used this personally (don't know how good it works in your case), it's just an idea. 
related: [Python digest/hash for string similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848991/python-digest-hash-for-string-similarity)

Comment: +1 Hashing the strings *before* you compare them is the only way to make this kind of problem fast. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex for an example how this works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, what your application aims at, but when working with sequences you might want to consider using [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page). An alternative way to calculate the distance between two DNA snipplets is using an alignment score (which is related to Levenshtein by non-constant alignement weights). Using biopython you could do a multiple sequence alignment and create a phylogenetic tree. If you'd like to have a faster solution, use BLAST which is a heuristical approach. This would be consistent solutions while yours depends on the random choice of the input sequences.

Concerning your initial question, there's no 'simple' solution to speed up your code.